# CURL SSL certificate problem in Bash and Docker Linux image but not Command Prompt

Tags: bash, docker, ssl, curl, nuget

For context, I am working on a full stack application behind company VPN, when docker composing my backend in C#, I get

> error NU1301: Unable to load the service index for source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json.

So testing connection with `curl https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json` works in CMD Prompt and loads the JSON just fine, but running that in bash and my docker image results in

```
$ curl https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json --verbose
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0*   Trying 152.199.4.184:443...
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0* Connected to api.nuget.org (152.199.4.184) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN: offers h2
* ALPN: offers http/1.1
*  CAfile: C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
*  CApath: none
} [5 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
} [512 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
{ [122 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Encrypted Extensions (8):
{ [15 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
{ [2645 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS alert, unknown CA (560):
} [2 bytes data]
* SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
* Closing connection 0
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
More details here: https://curl.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not
establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this situation and
how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned above.
```

Tried disconnecting from VPN and still resulted in same error.

Edit:
Error in Git Bash, separate from docker image, which is running Linux.
Beginning of dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["Wafer.csproj", "backend/"]
RUN curl https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json -v
RUN dotnet restore "backend/Wafer.csproj"
```

Run curl produces error above.
Dotnet restore says it is unable to load service index and can be traced back to the error of running that curl.

Comment: This is not programming or development and will likely be closed, but until then: does 'bash and my docker image' mean bash _in_ a docker container running the image, or two different things? what is in the docker image (and thus container) -- what curl, running what distro, and with what if any CA-certificates package? If bash is not in the container, what is it in, and the same questions for that? Does your VPN go through security devices that do SSL/TLS inspection and thus change the certificate(s)? Windows-supplied curl.exe uses the Windows store which may have been set by GPO.

Comment: Added more information to post (bash(Git Bash) and docker are separate), I believe I do not have any CA-certificates. I am asking for more information on the VPN

Comment: Okay, so git-bash is a port of mingw64 and its curl, as the log says, uses  `C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt` (which is also `/mingw64/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt` within git-bash, because its root is `c:/Program Files/Git`). In the not-too-current (Jan 2021) git-bash I have, that file does contain the DigiCert Global Root G2 cert (look for a PEM block whose last line is just `MrY=`), and `curl https://api.nuget.org` works (at the TLS level; I get an application error of course) ...

Comment: ... Similarly, that docker image is based on Debian 11 Bullseye and `dpkg-query -l curl ca-certificates` shows the relevant packages; `/etc/ssl/certs` has the relevant cert, and `curl` works for me. api.nuget.org actually uses a CDN so you might be getting a different server than I am; does `nslookup api.nuget.org` in Windows get you an address other than 152.199.4.184 ? Alternatively as I said businesses often do 'inspection' of traffic which would result in using different cert(s), which are usually installed in the Windows store used by curl.exe but neither git-bash nor docker/Debian. ...

Comment: ... Both git-bash and that Debian have ports of OpenSSL 1.1.1; in either try `openssl s_client -connect api.nuget.org:443` and see whether the received cert chain looks correct.